# Spring Batch with java configuration

Tags: java, spring-batch

I created a SpringBatch application with java configuration. I have a main method and a class that represents a job.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Starting Spring Batch Execution -------" );
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);        
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class FlatFileJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    /**
     * Create and configure job
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "Read RabbitMQ")
    public Job addFlatFileJob(){
        return jobs.get("carJob")
                .start(this.flatFileStep())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Create and configure the only step
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Step flatFileStep(){
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Car, Car> chunk(3)
                .reader(new CarItemReader())
                .processor(new CarItemProcessor())
                .writer(new CarItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception{
        JobRepository jobRepository = (JobRepository) new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        return jobRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/spring_batch");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxx");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I execute the app, an exception is thrown. Any idea what is the problem?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flatFileJob': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory neoway.com.job.FlatFileJob.jobs; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [neoway/com/job/FlatFileJob.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository neoway.com.job.FlatFileJob.jobRepository() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at neoway.com.App.main(App.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory neoway.com.job.FlatFileJob.jobs; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [neoway/com/job/FlatFileJob.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository neoway.com.job.FlatFileJob.jobRepository() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [neoway/com/job/FlatFileJob.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository neoway.com.job.FlatFileJob.jobRepository() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: are you sure you can have spaces within bean names in spring? "Read RabbitMQ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key this exception is `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository`.

Line with a exception: `JobRepository jobRepository = (JobRepository) new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();`.

Try to rewrite to this: `JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean()`

Comment: Thanks man. I got other exception now. Configure Spring Batch with java is hard for me. Do you know any site or book that explain this? The oficial guide is not good and I didn't find good explanation on internet.

Comment: There are many books and sites on this topic. For example http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/ , from my practice he often has good explanation different topics with simples examples. From books, maybe, "Spring Batch in Action" will be helpful. I'm not sure that help you, but perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setDatabaseType("SQLSERVER");
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

getObject is the convenience method for casting a JobRepositoryFactoryBean to JobRepository

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring Boot the easiest thing is to have your configuration class extend `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer` which will configure the `JobRepository` for you with the default configuration. It uses the data source that is being used in your application. If it cannot find a data source it will set up a in memory `JobRepository`.

For reference use the below link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html